# How to wait until a function is true or some time has passed in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Complete beginner at angular 2 and currently rather baffled by it all.

I have a function that needs to run when another returns true or after waiting half a second.

```
private myFunction(details: Stuff) {
    if (this.okToProceed(details))
    {
        this.doStuff(details);
    }
}
```

If it's not ok to proceed I want to try again in 100 ms but if I've waited 500ms then I want to doStuff anyway.

I've been messing around with setTimeout and setInterval and trying to make an observable of the okToProceed function but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

With some recursion (recurse with timeout until its okToProceed):

```
private myFunction(details: Stuff, i=0) {
    if (i>=5 || this.okToProceed(details)) {
        return this.doStuff(details);
    }
    setTimeout(this.myFunction.bind(this),100,i+1);
}
```

Or using some fancy ES7 doing real cool async stuff (no need to check recursively):

```
private async myFunction(details: Stuff) {
    if (await this.okToProceed(details)) {
        return this.doStuff(details);
    }
}
```

okToProceed must return a Promise like this:

```
okToProceed(details){
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why the function bind rather than just calling it? Also the ES7 won't break out after some time if okToProceed is never true, right?

Comment: @dibs 487 calling it would execute it right *now* which we dont want. And yes, the second just continues if the Promise is resolved somehow. You could do sth like setTimeout(reject,500) to automatically reject after a ceetain time